# When I copy and paste objects they are joined

Tags: objects

After pasting an object I make sure only one is selected, but both the original and the copy move together. I can enter edit mode and move one but they remain joined and ctrl+p to separate does not work. I'm not sure what has changed but I used to be able to copy an object and paste it as an entirely separate object.

Comment: I think you might be duplicating objects in edit mode instead of object mode.

Answer (score 1):

When you duplicate objects be sure you are in object mode. If you are in edit mode they may conjoin and be made a single object. I have trouble with this too.

Comment: Hmm that's not it, I am in object mode. Do you know of anything else it could be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and I had found the solution.

**NOTE**: *This is not a permanent solution, you would have to do this every time you would paste an object in the project file.*

Once you start to move your pasted object, there will be a tab called '*MOVE*'. There you will the selection of options of how you want to move the object.

Under the tab, there will be an option called '*Proportional Editing*'. You would want to turn that off.

Then you will be able to freely move your pasted object without interfering with the original object.

Hopes this helps!

[image]

Answer (score -3):

What i do is copy and paste the object, switch off the view ((hide in viewport) the eye next to the camera (Disable in render)) of the original object, the copy will remain in the same place, move the copy aside, switch the original object view back on.

Comment: If you copy and paste the same object when you want to duplicate it, you are making copies of all the stuff associated with the object like particle systems and materials as well. If you want to duplicate an object use duplicate function - shift+D. There will be no issues with moving the new duplicate as well with this operation.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys That comment should be the answer. The OP, myself, and probably most of the 1K people who have visited this question are making the mistake of using copy-paste instead of duplicate. With shift-D the duplicate of the object is immediately selected and put into move mode where the usual mouse and keyboard operations apply (as if you had selected it, in isolation, and pressed G). I'm not sure what you mean about the physics etc though, they are duplicated the same using either method?